# Von Neumann algebras with isomorphic sets of partial isometries

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Given a  von Neumann algebra $M$,  let
$$
  S(M) = \{u\in   M: uu^*u=u\}
  $$
be the set of partial isometries in $M$.  Given $u,v\in  S(M)$, it is well known that $uv \in S(M)$, provided $u^*u$ commutes
with $vv^*$.

Now suppose that $N$ is another von Neumann algebra and that
$$
  \varphi :S(M)\to S(N)
  $$
is a bijective function such that:

1. for every $u,v\in  S(M)$, such that $u^*u$ commutes with $vv^*$, one has that
   $\varphi (u)^*\varphi (u)$ commutes with $\varphi (v)\varphi (v^*)$, and
   $\varphi (uv)=\varphi (u)\varphi (v)$.
2. $\varphi ^{-1}$ satisfies (1).

Does it follow that $\varphi $ extends to an isomorphism from $M$ to $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider the map $\phi: u \mapsto u^*$ from the partial isometries in $M$ to the partial isometries in its opposite algebra $M^{op}$. One easily checks that it has the desired properties, but it cannot extend to a linear map because already e.g. $\phi(iI) = -iI \neq iI = i\phi(I)$.

If $M$ is not isomorphic to its opposite algebra, then we have an example where one has a map of the type described between non-isomorphic von Neumann algebras.

Comment: Fair enough! Let me think about it.

Comment: Thanks Nik. I'll accept your answer  but I suppose you will not be surprised if I follow up with the additional hypothesis $\phi(\lambda I)=\lambda I$.  Another sensible hypothesis one might try to use is $\phi(\sum u_i) =\sum\phi( u_i)$ for a countable set of partial isometries with pairwise orthogonal initial and final spaces.

Comment: How about using Dye'a theorem on projection lattices? Restrict $\phi$ to the projections and infer that there is a $*$-isomorphism implementing this restriction. Then we just have to show that $\phi$ is determined by its restriction to projections.

Comment: But that should be easy: we only need to show that if $\phi$ is the identity on projections then it is the identity on all partial isometries. For any $p \leq u^*u$ and $q \leq uu^*$ we have $\phi(puq) = p\phi(u)q$ and that should be enough to get $\phi(u) = u$.

Comment: This is just a sketch and it needs something more if $M$ has an $M_2$ direct summand (since Dye's theorem fails then).

Comment: How do you conclude that the map coming from Dye's Theorem is a *-isomorphism.  Isn't it only known to be a Jordan isomorphism?

Comment: Yeah, that's where you need the $\phi(\lambda I) = \lambda I$ condition.

Comment: I am confused.  If $M=N=M_n$, say $n\geq 3$, and $\phi(x)$ is the transpose of $x$, then $\phi$ in an orthoisomorphism of projection lattices, satisfying my condition (on projections) as well as mapping $\lambda I$ to itself, but it is not a *-isomorphism.

Comment: Oh, I was confused ... it is either a Jordan isomorphism or a Jordan antiisomorphism, and the $\phi(\lambda I) = \lambda I$ condition rules out the latter.

Comment: Nik, I think Dye's Theorem doesn't involve any conjugate linear maps.  You always get a (**linear**) Jordan *-isomorphism.  In fact, one may sometimes break such a map into the direct sum of a *-isomorphism and a *-anti-isomorphism (i.e. a linear map reversing multiplication).  Incidentally, Dye's map for the example in your answer is the (multiplication reversing) identity map.